# Функция, принимающая в аргумент арифметические операции

Tags: javascript, функции, математика

Есть функция, которая принимает арифметические операции в виде строки. Не понимаю, как бы так значение вставить в result, чтобы иметь возможность считать. Пыталась использовать eval

```js
function algebra(symbol){
    let a = 5;
    let b = 4;
    //let result = a(eval(symbol))b;
    console.log('Результат '+a+symbol+b+'=');
}
algebra('+');
algebra('-');
algebra('*');
```

Comment: eval is evil, но: `result = eval(a+symbol+b)`.

Comment: Как и написал уже @Yaant, вы не правильно eval использовали, надо не "знак" передавать а всю строку `eval(a + symbol + b)`

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант, можно просто написать `switch` для каждой операции

```js
function algebra(symbol) {
    const a = 5;
    const b = 4;
    let result = 0;
    
    switch(symbol) {
      case '+':
        result = a + b;
        break;
      case '-':
        result = a - b;
        break;
      case '*':
        result = a * b;
        break;
      case '/':
        result = a / b;
        break;
      default: throw new Error('Unknow operation')
    }
    
    console.log(`Результат ${a} ${symbol} ${b} = ${result}`);
}
algebra('+');
algebra('-');
algebra('*');
algebra('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function algebra(symbol){
    let a      = 5;
    let b      = 4;
    let result = eval(`${a}${symbol}${b}`);
    alert(`Результат ${a}${symbol}${b} = ${result}`);
}
algebra('+');
algebra('-');
algebra('*');
```

Если не знакомы с строками в ES6 (это вот такие строки: ``), то вот краткий [курс](https://learn.javascript.ru/es-string)